# Steghide "could not open file"

Tags: command-line

I am currently trying to extract an encrypted password from a steghide jpg file. I used the command, "steghide extract -sf file.jpg" and it prompted me to enter the passphrase. I typed it in correctly and it said "steghide: could not open the file"

Comment: Then either it doesn't find the file, or you don't have rights to read it, I would say...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing into the directory that the file is in first